# Can you put a gradient on a table row in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hover, css

When I mouse over a table row in a certain part of my table, I'd like the background to change to a linear gradient. The CSS is straightforward:

```
tbody.row-links tr:hover {
    background: ...typical multi-browser linear gradient code...
    color: #333C3E;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Works great in FF, Chrome, and Safari but not in any version of IE. I know the CSS is resolving because the color and cursor change. I tried placing the `filter` on the plain `<tr>` tag itself and still nothing. Does IE just ignore `filter` on table rows?

The best thing I can come up with is to apply the gradient to the `<td>`s of the row when the row is hovered, but that causes a lovely flickering while mousing about the row.

For now I'll just give IE a solid color background on hover. Has anyone else tried this and figured it out?

Comment: Why don't you use a gradient image as background in your hover. Every browser will show.

Comment: I prefer the flexibility of a vector gradient. It looks good at any resolution or zoom. Plus, if I change my table design, I don't need to make another image. It's working elsewhere except this one case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
```

for IE9

OR

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
```

for IE10

older IE only with images.

Comment: `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333c3e',endColorstr='#222829')` is working great in IE elsewhere for me. It's just not working for the table row.